# Find the average value of $x^2 - y^2 + 2y$ over the circle $|z - 5 + 2i| = 3$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Find the average value of $x^2 - y^2 + 2y$ over the circle $|z - 5 + 2i| = 3$.

Could someone please explain how to do this. I keep getting an answer of 17, but my professor says that is incorrect.

Comment: What did you try for this one?

Comment: Please add your ideas in it

Comment: Write $x=5+3\cos(\theta)$ and $y=-2+3\sin(\theta)$, where $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.  Then, what do you do when you want to take an average of a function $f(\theta)$ over the angle $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, recognize that the circle has center at $5-2i$ and radius $3$. So you can parametrize it using $x=5+3\cos(t)$ and $y=-2+3\sin(t)$.

So you are now asking for the average value of
$$
\begin{align}
&(5+3\cos(t))^2-(-2+3\sin(t))^2+2(-2+3\sin(t)) \\
&=17+30\cos(t)+18\sin(t)+9\cos^2(t)-9\sin^2(t)
\end{align}
$$
where $t$ runs over $[0,2\pi]$. Can you take it from there? Note that $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ average to $0$, and whatever $\sin^2(t)$ averages out to, it matches what $\cos^2(t)$ averages out to.

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty much what I did on my own, and I kept coming up with the answer 17, but our professor said that wasn't an option, so I thought I was super far off. Reassuring to know that I was on track. Maybe I made a mistake with the averages.

Comment: Not that it makes things much simpler but one could note that $\cos^2t - \sin^2t$ is simply $\cos2t$ which directly gives average as $0$.